# JSON Doesn't perform the edit action in MVC

Tags: jquery, sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpGet]
    [LogInFilter]
    public PartialViewResult MemberEdit(Int32 MemID)  // Update PartialView  
    {
        MemberTbl Mem = db.MemberTbls.Where(x => x.ID == MemID).FirstOrDefault();
        MemberTbl MemInfo = new MemberTbl();

        MemInfo.ID = Mem.ID;
        MemInfo.Name = Mem.Name;
        MemInfo.Post = Mem.Post;
        MemInfo.Phone = Mem.Phone;

        return PartialView(MemInfo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [LogInFilter]
    public JsonResult MemberEdit(GarhwalBhawan.Models.MemberTbl MemID)  // Record Update 
    {

        MemberTbl MemDt = db.MemberTbls.Where(x => x.ID == MemID.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MemDt.Name = MemID.Name;
            MemDt.Post = MemID.Post;
            MemDt.Phone = MemID.Phone;
            db.SaveChanges();
            myMessage = "Success";
        }

        else
        {
            myMessage = "Failed";
        }
        return Json(myMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I've the above ActionResult in My Controller. Now I want to save the field with JSON with help of ID.
I've created the following JQuery method on the click of that button.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#memberSave').click(function () {
            var Name = $("#Name").val();
            var Post = $("#Post").val();
            var Phone = $("#Phone").val();

            var Member = {
               "Name": Name, "Post": Post,
                "Phone": Phone
            };
            $.post("/Admin/MemberEdit", Member,
            function (data) {
                if (data == "Success") {
                    window.location.href = 'MemberView';
                }
                else if (data == "Failed") {
                    alert('Cannot Save!! Please Fill all Details or Contact Support')
                }

                else {
                    alert(data);
                }
            }, 'json');

        });
    });
```

```html
Thus I've created a button:-
 <input id="memberSave" type="button" value="Save Changes" />
```

But on click this button is showing error:- 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
And Getting me the alert :- 
  alert('Cannot Save!! Please Fill all Details or Contact Support').

Please Help.

Comment: You need to learn to debug your code! Open your browser tools (Network tab) and look at the response - it will contain the details of the error. And you code can simply be `$.post("/Admin/MemberEdit", $('form').serialize(), function (data) {`. But what is the point of this - your just wanting to redirect if successful, so DO NOT use ajax - make a normal submit.

Comment: And you error almost certainly occurs because you never pass a value for the ID property so `MemID.ID` is `0` and `MemDt` is therefore `null` and `MemDt.Name = MemID.Name;` throws a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: what will $('form').serialize() will do in above code?

Comment: It will replace the first 7 lines of your `$('#memberSave').click(function () {` function :) - no point writing all that code when there is already a function that will do it all correctly for you

Comment: You cannot just edit you question to now show the correct code - its no longer a question! (I have rolled back your changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not put the parameter “ID” into your parameter “Member”